# Sort list with Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have an error with python 2.7
I am trying to sort a list of element. 
Here is my code:

```
index=7 
print(len(myList)) #print 16
sortedList = sorted(myList,key=lambda x: float(x[index]),reverse=True)
```

I can't understand why I am having this error, my index is less than the list length... Any ideas?

```
    sortedList = sorted(myList,key=lambda x: float(x[index]),reverse=True)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: what does `list` comprise of?

Comment: *What error?* We can't read your mind.

Comment: You're indexing into the lists **contained within `myList`**, at least one of which apparently has fewer than `7` elements. Try `map(len, myList)` to see these lengths.

Comment: A list of strings. And I am casting the list[index] to float for sorting.

Comment: Since `myList` is a list of strings and `index` is 7, the function `lambda x: float(x[index])` gets the 7th character of each string in `myList` and attempts to convert it to a floating-point number. This is almost certainly not a useful thing to do. I'd like to help you fix your program, but I can't do so without further information. What are you _really_ trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your key for sorting and the error you see, I'm assuming that `myList` is a list of lists.

It seems that you're trying to sort the members of `myList` by the value of their 8th member item.

Unfortunately, not all the members of `myList` have 8 members, so you are hitting the error you see: `IndexError: list index out of range`

You haven't spotted this, because you're checking the length of `myList`, not the length of its member lists.

You can do this check by trying:

```
for sublist in myList:
    print(len(sublist))
```

I suspect that at least one of them is less than 8.  Let me demonstrate with code:

```
import random
working_list = []
bad_list = []

for n in range(16):
    #Make a sublist of random integers - 10 members long
    good_sublist = [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(10)]
    #make a sublist of random integers from 0 to 15 members long
    bad_sublist = [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(n)]
    working_list.append(good_sublist)
    bad_list.append(bad_sublist)

# Your code from here on in
index=7 
sortedList = sorted(working_list,key=lambda x: float(x[index]),reverse=True)
print sortedList

# all Good! Each sublist has 10 members - the list is sorted by the 7th member

sortedList = sorted(bad_list,key=lambda x: float(x[index]),reverse=True)
print sortedList
```

#### Small stylistic note

Camel case e.g. `myList`, `sortedList` is generally avoided for variable names, with `my_list` or `sorted_list` being preferred (see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).  I've retained your names in my code example for ease of reference, but I'd recommend you move to the underscore style for maintainability, ease of reading by other python coders etc.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the tips, it makes more sense to me now :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not that your  `index` is less than `len(list)` But in  this function

```
    sortedList = sorted(myList,key=lambda x: float(x[index]),reverse=True)
```

each item in list is passed as `x` So it is  trying to access the `x[7]` which may not be true in all the cases